# Convert timezone of np.datetime64 without loss of precision

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, timezone

I have a DataFrame, one of whose columns is of type datetime64[ns]. These represent times in "Europe/London" timezone, and are on nanosecond-level of precision. (The data is coming from an external system)

I need to convert these to datetime64[ns] entries that represent *UTC* time instead. So in other words, bump each day by 0 or by 1 hours, depending on whether the entry is during summer time or not.

What is the best way of doing this?

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any timezone support baked into np.datetime64. At the same time, I can't just directly convert to/work with datetime.datetime objects, as that'd mean loss of precision. The only thing I could think of so far is converting np.datetime64 to datetime.datetime, adjusting timezones, getting some sort of timedelta between unadjusted and adjusted datetime.datetime, and then apply that timedelta back to np.datetime64. Sounds like a lot of hoops to jump through though, for something which I'm hoping can be done more easily?

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to add a [minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this that demonstrates the problem you are having? It will be easier to answer the question with something to play with.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears `pandas` has some built-in support for this, using the `dt` accessor:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt_arr = np.array(['2019-05-01T12:00:00.000000010',
                   '2019-05-01T12:00:00.000000100',],
                  dtype='datetime64[ns]')

df = pd.DataFrame(dt_arr)

# Represent naive datetimes as London time
df[0] = df[0].dt.tz_localize('Europe/London')

# Convert to UTC
df[0] = df[0].dt.tz_convert("UTC")

print(df)
                                    # 0
# 0 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000000010+00:00
# 1 2019-05-01 11:00:00.000000100+00:00
```

Assuming you are starting with some ISO 8601 strings in your `np.datetime64[ns]`, you can use `dt.tz_localize` to assign a time zone to them, then `dt.tz_convert` to convert them into another time zone.

I will warn though that if they came in as integers like `1556708400000000010`, there's a good chance that they *already* represent UTC, since timestamps given in seconds or nanoseconds are usually [Unix epoch times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), which are independent of the time zone they were recorded in (it's a number of seconds/nanoseconds after the Unix epoch, not a civil time).